# Mysterious blank folder keeps showing up on my desktop

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-explorer

I have a folder with no name on my Windows desktop.  The name is *literally* empty:

[image]

I'd like to get rid of this.  Oh, easy you say?  Well here's where things get interesting.  First, if I click on it and hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>, it just comes back within a day, like a zombie coming back from the dead.

Okay, great maybe I can hide it or something.  Well, if I try to right click on it to modify the folder properties, it becomes clear this isn't actually a real file:

[image]

If I select "Create shortcut", nothing happens.  If I double click on it to try to open it, nothing happens.  What does the actual file system look like, you ask?  Nothing:

[image]

Any ideas on how to kill this thing once and for all?

**Update:**

Contents of `desktop.ini`:

```
[LocalizedFileNames]
migwiz.lnk=@%windir%\system32\migwiz\wet.dll,-588
```

Contents of Public folder `desktop.ini`:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21799
```

**Another Update:**

I can *Cut* the folder and paste it somewhere else on the desktop.  If I *paste* the folder to some other folder on my disk, I get this helpful error:

[image]

Comment: If you have a look inside desktop.ini you may see the definition of the "folder". This happens after a restart? Or even if you leave the system running?

Comment: Try `dir /ah C:\Users\Public\Desktop`

Comment: @Steven - Same thing. Just one `desktop.ini` hidden file (no normal files)

Comment: @JulianKnight - Added the contents of both `desktop.ini` files to the post.

Comment: If you "Cut" it, can you paste it someplace else?  Have you run a disk check yet (to ensure there's no file-system/disk corruption)?

Comment: Try `dir /a` against both user and public desktop folders

Comment: try `dir /X` (also, run cmd.exe as admin). This will show you the auto-generated 8.3 filenames for all files and folders. I made a folder with filename `alt+0160` as the filename and dir shows blank, but the 8.3 name is `9dec~1`

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - If I paste the folder somewhere else, I get an error (See updated screen shot above)

Comment: I don't believe it is a real folder but rather a Windows Explorer indirection that has gone wrong. Clearly something is recreating it. Have you checked for malware? Anything odd running?

Comment: @JulianKnight - We use Trend Micro here for viruses, and it says everything is okay.

Comment: It looks like it might be an OS search/Office-related product ({138508bc-1e03-49ea-9c8f-ea9e1d05d65d}), possibly a conflict with office 2010 and 2013 (?)

Comment: I don't like to be a naysayer but ...  no AV is perfect. You should check manually for odd things running and maybe run some anti-malware checks too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to this discussion, this issue seems to be related to remnants of an old Microsoft Office 2010 installation.

http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/256250-random-empty-folder-keeps-appearing-desktop.html

The fix suggests searching the registry for `138508BC-1E03-49EA-9C8F-EA9E1D05D65D` and removing occurrences.

Comment: see also: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/b7f508b9-566f-4c1a-9b66-d121e483d2f7/lync-2013-client-windows-search-results

Comment: Good catch, +1 from me

Comment: Cool, removed a bunch of those keys from the registry.  Gonna reboot just to be safe.  If it doesn't come back tomorrow, I'll mark this as answered.  Thanks!

Comment: Welp, it stayed dead.  Yay!

Answer (score 8):

Going to

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\

and removing these keys:

> 138508BC-1E03-49EA-9C8F-EA9E1D05D65D
>
> 0875DCB6-C686-4243-9432-ADCCF0B9F2D7

appears to have taken care of this bizarre problem.

Comment: Would be nice if what these keys did were documented somewhere. Removing keys with arbitrary/cryptic GUIDs seems scary.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error here. Not a folder icon though but an empty file icon.

Did a full system scan for malware / virus: Nothing.

I then deleted the two regdb keys as mentioned in the suggestion/tip above and the problem went away immediately.

### Deleted entries

- [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace{0875DCB6-C686-4243-9432-ADCCF0B9F2D7}]
  @="Microsoft OneNote Namespace Extension for Windows Desktop Search"
- [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace{138508bc-1e03-49ea-9c8f-ea9e1d05d65d}]
  @="MAPI Shell Folder"

Answer (score 0):

I also had Office 365 (2015+) click-n-run and Office 2010 installed. Office 365 was uninstalled, Office 2010 is still running on the system. PC running windows 10.

To fix search/run on your PC for

> regedit

**Backup your registry or the class you are editing.**
I fixed the issue using [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/932234/1031533) but you can also remove the key found by trying to move the foder and getting the ID from the error message (as described in the problem description - Another Update) between the curly brackets *::{xx_ID}*

In my case the issue was in:

> [HKEY_USERS\{your-user-sid}\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CLSID]

After removing those keys I deleted the icon from desktop and restarted.

The icon is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Please open registry and find this path..

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\
```

Then find the name without any value. Usually this one `{138508BC-1E03-49EA-9C8F-EA9E1D05D65D}` has not set any value. Please delete that entry by right-clicking and <kbd>delete</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and followed the directions given but unfortunately those didn’t work. I then realized that the file had a its own NameSpace directory. If you open explore/desktop and click the file, you’ll see it’s NameSpace below where in file information would be displayed. Once you find the same NameSpace in Regedit you should delete it. This will rid of the file once you refresh/F5 Regedit.

Answer (score -1):

1.**Uninstall** the Microsoft office.

2 **Delete** the "office" files from C:\ProgramData\Microsoft

3.**Rename** the the file Microsoft Help as "Microsoft Help.old" from C:\ProgramData

4.**Restart** the system